# Web based command to open package in Unity like asset store

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a webpage to hold some of my .unitypackages. Would anyone know of a command in html to send a file to Unity and open, similar to the prompt you get when you download and object using the Asset store?

Or maybe a link to where it would be in the actual docs?
I'm having a hard time finding any such command.

Edit:  I think this is what I'm looking for

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Comment: `Edit: ..` -> Nope ^^ That's how to interact between JavaScript and a WebGL build embedded on the same HTML page .. that's not what you want

Comment: Have you tried simply opening it after download? That's basically how Assets store worked previously (now not anymore, after obtaining an asset you have to load it vis the package manager within Unity itself) and how UnityHub works now. It works since only one instance of this program is on your PC while you might have multiple Unity instances opened so the browser wouldn't know in which to open the unitypackge (afaik it will be the last focused one)

Comment: I really thought I had it too. :\  I can definitely open it directly.  But the idea was to try and see if I could set up something web based that would take my file and pass it to an Open function in Unity.  Thank you for the info btw.

Comment: Looks like it may be Web Request that I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think it will be anything from the Unity API at all since there is no Unity running on your web page ;)

Comment: Trying to find a different solution.  Thanks again for the info!